# Scraping through all pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this websites: voxnews.info

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd

web='https://voxnews.info'
def main(req, num, web):
    r = req.get(web+"/page/{}/".format(num))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    goal = [(x.time.text, x.h1.a.get_text(strip=True), x.select_one("span.cat-links").get_text(strip=True), x.p.get_text(strip=True))
           for x in soup.select("div.site-content")]

    return goal


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        fs = [executor.submit(main, req, num) for num in range(1, 2)] # need to scrape all the webpages in the website
        allin = []
        for f in fs:
            allin.extend(f.result())
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
            allin, columns=["Date", "Title", "Category", "Content"])
        print(df)
```

But the code has two problems:

- the first one is that I am not scraping all the pages (I currently put 1 and 2 in the range, but I would need all the pages);
- it does not save correctly the dates.

If could have a look at the code and tell me how to improve it in order to fix these two issues,it would be awesome.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to scrape the data from all the articles on the page?

Comment: Hi goalie 1998, yes it is right. I would need to scrape dates titles category and content of each article in all pages.

Comment: Ok, I'll work on something. I will say first, that the articles don't have a p tag associated with them that I can see. And what format do you want the dates in?

Comment: thanks goalie 1998. I have tried my best to write down some code that could work, but unfortunately it is not doing what I would have been expected. Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some minor changes.

First it isn't necessary to use requests.Session() for single requests - you aren't trying to save data between requests.

A minor change to how you had your `with` statement, I don't know if it's more correct, or just how I do it, you don't need all of the code to run with the executer still open.

I gave you two options for parsing the date, either as it's written on the site, a string in Italian, or as a datetime object.

I didn't see any "p" tag within the articles, so I removed that part. It seems in order to get the "content" of the articles, you would have to actually navigate to and scrape them individually. I removed that line from the code.

In your original code, you weren't getting every single article on the page, just the first one of each. There is only one "div.site-content" tag per page, but multiple "article" tags. That's what that change is.

And finally, I prefer find over select, but that's just my style choice. This worked for me for the first three pages, I didn't try the entire site. Be careful when you do run this, 78 blocks of 30 requests might get you blocked...

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd
import datetime


def main(num, web):
    r = requests.get(web+"/page/{}/".format(num))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    html = soup.find("div", class_="site-content")
    articles = html.find_all("article")
    
    # Date as string In italian
    goal = [(x.time.get_text(), x.h1.a.get_text(strip=True), x.find("span", class_="cat-links").get_text(strip=True)) for x in articles]
    # OR as datetime object
    goal = [(datetime.datetime.strptime(x.time["datetime"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"), x.h1.a.get_text(strip=True), x.find("span", class_="cat-links").get_text(strip=True)) for x in articles]

    return goal


web='https://voxnews.info'

r = requests.get(web)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
last_page = soup.find_all("a", class_="page-numbers")[1].get_text()
last_int = int(last_page.replace(".",""))

### BE CAREFUL HERE WITH TESTING, DON'T USE ALL 2,320 PAGES ###
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    fs = [executor.submit(main, num, web) for num in range(1, last_int)]

allin = []
for f in fs:
    allin.extend(f.result())
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    allin, columns=["Date", "Title", "Category"])
print(df)
```

Comment: You would have to get the href for each page, navigate to it and then scrape those pages separately.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch results from all pages, not just one or ten pages (i.e. hardcoded), the best solution is to use an infinite `while` loop and test for something (button, element) that will cause it to exit.

This solution is better than a hardcoded `for` loop since the [`while` loop will go through all pages no matter how many there are until a certain condition is fulfilled](https://python.plainenglish.io/pagination-techniques-to-scrape-data-from-any-website-in-python-779cd32bd514#74dc). In our case, this is the presence of a button on the page (`.next` CSS selector):

```py
if soup.select_one(".next"):
    page_num += 1
else:
    break
```

You can also add a limit on the number of pages, upon reaching which the cycle will also stop:

```py
limit = 20       # paginate through 20 pages
if page_num == limit:
    break
```

Check code in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-voxnews-data-pagination-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
}

data = []

page_num = 1

limit = 20                 # page limit

while True:
    html = requests.get(f"https://voxnews.info/page/{page_num}", headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

    print(f"Extracting page: {page_num}")

    print("-" * 10)
  
    for result in soup.select(".entry-header"):
        title = result.select_one(".entry-title a").text
        category = result.select_one(".entry-meta:nth-child(1)").text.strip()
        date = result.select_one(".entry-date").text
          
        data.append({
            "title": title,
            "category": category,
            "date": date
        })

    # Condition for exiting the loop when the specified number of pages is reached.
    if page_num == limit:
        break
  
    if soup.select_one(".next"):
        page_num += 1
    else:
        break  

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
    {
    "title": "Italia invasa dai figli degli immigrati: “Italiani pezzi di merda” – VIDEO",
    "category": "BREAKING NEWS, INVASIONE, MILANO, VIDEO",
    "date": "Novembre 23, 2022"
  },
  {
    "title": "Soumahoro accusato di avere fatto sparire altri 200mila euro – VIDEO",
    "category": "BREAKING NEWS, POLITICA, VIDEO",
    "date": "Novembre 23, 2022"
  },
  {
    "title": "Città invase da immigrati: “Qui comandiamo noi” – VIDEO",
    "category": "BREAKING NEWS, INVASIONE, VENEZIA, VIDEO",
    "date": "Novembre 23, 2022"
  },
  # ...
]
```

There's a [13 ways to scrape any public data from any website](https://serpapi.com/blog/13-ways-to-scrape-any-data-from-any-website/) blog post if you want to know more about website scraping.